# Property "CStringValidator.0" is not defined. YII

Tags: php, yii

I'm new 
 on Yii and find error message

```
Property "CStringValidator.0" is not defined.
```

The Error Line is on View script

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($data, 'NIP','');?>
```

Can Anyone to Fix this Problem?

Im very Appreciated Your Answer.

Thanks

Comment: http://yiiapi.com/CHtml#activeTextField-detail

Comment: @tinybyte, oke it solve, the problem is on the Model File.